# MySql add new column as result

Tags: mysql, select

I have this query:

```
SELECT v2.longitude AS something FROM points AS v2
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT v2.longitude AS something,2*something FROM points AS v2
```

but it fails with

> `points.longitude` is a float number

How can I fix this?

EDIT- Here is an example of the current query:

```
$query="
SELECT 
v2.longitude AS xa,
v2.latitude AS ya,
v3.longitude AS xb,
v3.latitude AS yb, 
(yb-ya)/(xb-xa) AS l,
-1/l AS l_katheto,
(l*xa-l_katheto*$tetmimenh+ya-y1)/(l_katheto-l) AS x_tomh, 
l*(x_tomh-xa)+ya AS y_katheto,
min(
    sqrt(
        (v2.longitude-$tetmimenh)*
        (v2.longitude-$tetmimenh)+
        (v2.latit‌​ude-$tetagmenh)*
        (v2.latitude-$tetagmenh)
    ),
    sqrt(
        (v3.longitude-$tetmimenh)*
        (v3.long‌​itude-$tetmimenh)+
        (v3.latitude-$tetagmenh)*
        (v3.latitude-$tetagmenh)
    ),
    sqrt(
        ($tetmi‌​menh-x_tomh)*
        ($tetmimenh-x_tomh)+
        ($tetagmenh-y_tomh)*
        ($tetagmenh-y_tomh)
    )
) 
FROM 
segments AS v1 
JOIN points AS v2 ON v1.from_point=v2.point_id 
JOIN points AS v3 ON v3.point_id=v1.to_point";
```

Comment: use concat(2*something) as something..

Comment: You can't reuse an alias in the same select list or reference it in the WHERE clause. You can either write the column name out twice, or wrap it in a subquery (which is nonsense if just to avoid using a the name twice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SELECT v2.longitude AS something,2*v2.longitude AS something2 FROM points AS v2
```

Comment: why? There's nothing wrong with using several times the same field, if needed.

Comment: `     $query="SELECT v2.longitude AS xa,v2.latitude AS ya,v3.longitude AS xb,v3.latitude AS yb, (yb-ya)/(xb-xa) AS l, -1/l AS l_katheto, (l*xa-l_katheto*$tetmimenh+ya-y1)/(l_katheto-l) AS x_tomh, l*(x_tomh-xa)+ya AS y_katheto,min(sqrt((v2.longitude-$tetmimenh)*(v2.longitude-$tetmimenh)+(v2.latitude-$tetagmenh)*(v2.latitude-$tetagmenh)),sqrt((v3.longitude-$tetmimenh)*(v3.longitude-$tetmimenh)+(v3.latitude-$tetagmenh)*(v3.latitude-$tetagmenh)),sqrt(($tetmimenh-x_tomh)*($tetmimenh-x_tomh)+($tetagmenh-y_t...
`

Comment: `omh)*($tetagmenh-y_tomh))) FROM segments AS v1 JOIN points AS v2 ON v1.from_point=v2.point_id JOIN points AS v3 ON v3.point_id=v1.to_point";`

Do you understand now?

Comment: It's unreadable. Pleas update your initial question with that information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but given the query that you gave in an earlier comment, I can only comment on what I understand at the moment.

Your query in your comment to @Jocelyn

```
SELECT 
v2.longitude AS xa,
    /* you can use xa2 for the rest of your calcs */
2*(v2.longitude) as xa2,
v2.latitude AS ya,
v3.longitude AS xb,
    /* if you need it for the other long as well */
2*(v3.longitude) as xb2,
v3.latitude AS yb, 
(yb-ya)/(xb-xa) AS l,
    /* BTW, the (l) makes this and the next few line hard to read */
-1/l AS l_katheto,
    /* is this a negative inverse? */
(l*xa-l_katheto*$tetmimenh+ya-y1)/(l_katheto-l) AS x_tomh, 
l*(x_tomh-xa)+ya AS y_katheto,
min(
    sqrt(
        (v2.longitude-$tetmimenh)*
        (v2.longitude-$tetmimenh)+
        (v2.latit‌​ude-$tetagmenh)*
        (v2.latitude-$tetagmenh)
    ),
    sqrt(
        (v3.longitude-$tetmimenh)*
        (v3.long‌​itude-$tetmimenh)+
        (v3.latitude-$tetagmenh)*
        (v3.latitude-$tetagmenh)
    ),
    sqrt(
        ($tetmi‌​menh-x_tomh)*
        ($tetmimenh-x_tomh)+
        ($tetagmenh-y_tomh)*
        ($tetagmenh-y_tomh)
    )
) 
FROM 
segments AS v1 
JOIN points AS v2 ON v1.from_point=v2.point_id 
JOIN points AS v3 ON v3.point_id=v1.to_point
```